Blazor server app not working on one computer but working on others
I have a Blazor server app that I develop. In this there is a scoped css for a component and 2 components from a nuget package.
When I run this on my virtual developer machine with Visual Studio 2022 (17.10.0) it does not work. I get this in the dev-tools console:
:44313/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.RichEdit/dx-blazor-richedit.bs5.css:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
:44313/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/blazing-berry.bs5.min.css:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
:44313/MyComponent.styles.css:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
blazor.server.js:1 [2024-05-28T06:40:43.580Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:44313/_blazor'.
blazor.server.js:1 [2024-05-28T06:40:43.847Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44313/_blazor?id=sD_elkEuLZmwWvGAeWYbbw.
:44313/_content/DevExpress.Blazor/modules/dx-blazor-95ab6d2f.js:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
:44313/_content/DevExpress.Blazor/modules/dx-form-layout-d94d1af4.js:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
blazor.server.js:1 [2024-05-28T06:40:45.559Z] Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Popup.Internal.PopupRendererModelBase.ClientSideShowAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Popup.Internal.PopupBaseModel.<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<<ShowAsync>g__ShowAsyncCore|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Popup.Internal.TaskExtensions.LogCancel[T](Task`1 task, CancellationToken token, ILogger logger, String message)
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Popup.Internal.PopupBaseModel.ShowAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Popup.Internal.AsyncTask.InvokeAsync()
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Popup.Internal.PopupBaseModel.VisibleChangedAsync()
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Popup.Internal.PopupBaseModel.AfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Popup.Internal.TaskExtensions.WaitOrCancel(Task task, CancellationToken token)
   at DevExpress.Blazor.DxPopupBase.<>c__DisplayClass230_0.<<OnAfterRenderAsync>g__AfterRenderLocalAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Popup.Internal.TaskExtensions.SafeInvokeAsync(Task task, CancellationTokenSource tcs)
   at DevExpress.Blazor.DxPopupBase.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
log @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 [2024-05-28T06:40:45.560Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
MyComponent.styles.css:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
dx-blazor-richedit.bs5.css:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
blazing-berry.bs5.min.css:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

I have enabled "Trace" level logs and in the output window I get:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44313/MyComponent.styles.css - - -
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware: Trace: All hosts are allowed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HstsMiddleware: Debug: The host 'localhost' is excluded. Skipping HSTS header.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44313/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.RichEdit/dx-blazor-richedit.bs5.css - - -
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Debug: The request path /MyComponent.styles.css does not match an existing file
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware: Trace: All hosts are allowed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/MyComponent.styles.css'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HstsMiddleware: Debug: The host 'localhost' is excluded. Skipping HSTS header.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: Endpoint 'Fallback {*path:nonfile}' with route pattern '{*path:nonfile}' was rejected by constraint 'path':'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Constraints.NonFileNameRouteConstraint' with value 'MyComponent.styles.css' for the request path '/MyComponent.styles.css'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Debug: The request path /_content/DevExpress.Blazor.RichEdit/dx-blazor-richedit.bs5.css does not match an existing file
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: Endpoint 'Fallback {*path:nonfile}' with route pattern '{*path:nonfile}' is not valid for the request path '/MyComponent.styles.css'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.RichEdit/dx-blazor-richedit.bs5.css'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware: Debug: Request did not match any endpoints
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: Endpoint 'Fallback {*path:nonfile}' with route pattern '{*path:nonfile}' was rejected by constraint 'path':'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Constraints.NonFileNameRouteConstraint' with value '_content/DevExpress.Blazor.RichEdit/dx-blazor-richedit.bs5.css' for the request path '/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.RichEdit/dx-blazor-richedit.bs5.css'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44313/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/blazing-berry.bs5.min.css - - -
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: Endpoint 'Fallback {*path:nonfile}' with route pattern '{*path:nonfile}' is not valid for the request path '/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.RichEdit/dx-blazor-richedit.bs5.css'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer: Debug: Connection ID "18230571306091282445" disconnecting.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware: Debug: Request did not match any endpoints
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44313/MyComponent.styles.css - 404 - - 83.5307ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware: Trace: All hosts are allowed.



The thing is that on my "local" computer this does not happen. Also it does not happen on my coworkers computers.
The project has .NET 8.0 as target framework.
I get the same result when I:

run as "stand-alone" blazor app
hosted in ISS Express
disregard Visual Studio and run in a cmd-prompt with help of "dotnet run" command

The same problem happens in all the browsers I have tested.
I have uninstalled all .NET 8.* from the computer including the Visual Studio ASP.NET 8.0 components and reinstalled them. Same problem.
For each step I have remove bin/obj folders and rebuild everything.
What can I do to correct this error? Has anyone else come across it?
I rather not do a "reinstall everything from scratch".
----edit
I have created a server blazor app with template "Blazor Web App". .NET 8.0, Server, per page/Component, "Configure for HTTPS" and I get same error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
BlazorApp1.styles.css:1


Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

and the page looks weird because no css.
The output for log level "trace":
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
Request starting HTTP/2 GET localhost:7067/… - - -
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[2]
All hosts are allowed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1000]
No candidates found for the request path '/BlazorApp1.styles.css'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[2]
Request did not match any endpoints
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HstsMiddleware[2]
The host 'localhost' is excluded. Skipping HSTS header.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[5]
The request path /BlazorApp1.styles.css does not match an existing file
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
Request finished HTTP/2 GET localhost:7067/… - 404 0 - 34.6410ms
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http2[49]
Connection id "0HN3UVCI8T023" sending HEADERS frame for stream ID 11 with length 37 and flags END_STREAM, END_HEADERS.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[16]
Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code. Request path: GET localhost:7067/…, Response status code: 404

Thank you

Observation: All the errors look like they come from DevExpress - is it installed correctly?

Not all the errors, the scoped css is not part of DevExpress. And yes, I have references to devexpress in other blazor projects that works.

NP.  The url also looks wrong :44313/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/blazing-berry.bs5.min.css, is it the same in both working and not-working contexts?

the url  is the same in both. What I understand the folder "_content" is a "magical" folder that do exists on harddrive but ASP.NET should expand the paths to paths inside the nuget-packages.

For me it seems that ASP.NET do not expand the expected file path in CandidateRejectedByConstraint in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Routing/src/Matching/DfaMatcher.cs.
But I have not IDEA why this is happening and how I can configure it to make it happen.

If you build a Net8 Blazor project from the template does it work in both contexts?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
